# ¿Como crear varios paneles en uno? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy desarrollando en Java un Programa CRUD, y ando utilizando JavaFX para la interface grafica.
Tengo varias ventanas. 1 de inicio, Varias que muestran las tablas de las relaciones y 1 de configuración como se muestran acá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, los botones tanto de "Oficiales" como "Reos" son las tablas de mi Base de Datos, sin embargo faltan como 5 Tablas mas.

Mi cuestion es la siguiente:

Al momento de hace click en cada boton de la izquierda, el panel principal se vuelve invisible y hago visible el que desee. sin embargo, quiero que al momento de hacer click en los botones Oficiales, Reos, etc, no me cambie de panel, si no que solo cambie el titulo Superior y la tabla, para no tener que estar creando muchos paneles con exactamente los mismos botones, a excepcion del titulo y la tabla que muestra la información...

No se si me he explicado bien, pero si alguien sabe como ayudar, les agradeceria

Answer (score -1):

Quita el evento que hace invisible/visible el panel.

En su lugar, al realizar un clic en un botón, ocultas todos los títulos y tablas (podrías hacerlo con un método auxiliar para reusar código) y haces visible solo el título y la tabla correspondiente a cada botón.

De cualquier manera, si deseas hacerlo, debes tener cuidado con la botonera. Ya que tienes un botón para 5 tablas distintas encimadas una a la otra (aunque 4 estén invisibles), deberías de agregar una comprobación. Por ejemplo, al presionar "Añadir", la acción debería realizarse sobre la única tabla visible. Esto puedes resolverlo almacenando el nombre de la tabla activa en una variable.